# React/Jest How to wait until useEffect has run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have the following code:

```
const doSomething = useCallback(someFunction);

useEffect(() => {
  // doSomething takes in the data and invokes the callback at the end as newData
  doSomething(data, (newData: string) => {
    setData(newData);
  });
}, [data, doSomething]);
```

When I want to test this, it only works when I use `setTimeout` with 1 or more ms. I suppose this is because the function in `useEffect` has not run yet and thus has not updated the component, correct me if I'm wrong. How can I work around this without `setTimeout`? Or do I need a completely different approach? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the test code. Otherwise it is hard to tell.

Comment: Test code is not relevant in this case, it's about waiting until the hook has finished doing its thing and finished rendering. The problem (I think) is that when I render the component in the test and assert the values, it is actually the original component that did not run `useEffect` yet. So when I wrap my test (excluding the setup rendering of the component) in a `setTimeout` of just 1 ms, it 'magically' works. I wonder if I'm using the right approach or if I'm not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try a wrapper function, for example:

```
async function handleSomething(){
    const res = await doSomthing()
    setData(res)
}
```

then call this function inside useEffect.